# Object Oriented Analysis and Design, design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, ooad

I'm studying composite design pattern. I just wanted to ask that can a leaf in a composite pattern inherit from any other class than component?

[image]

Comment: Is there somebody to answer?

Comment: Why couldn't it? In most OO languages, you **always** inherit from a base Object class anyway. And even then, there is no design pattern police that will send you in jail if you adapt the pattern to your needs.

Comment: The arrow from "Team" to "Participant" in your diagram should be a Aggregation arrow (diamond) pointing to Team, because "One Team has multiple Participants".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Composite` pattern, `Composite` and a `Leaf` implement the same interface `Component`. That's the point of the pattern.

The purpose is that you can write code which treats a `Leaf` or a `Composite` consisting of multiple `Leaf`s (or multiple sub-`Composite`s) the same way.

When you are using an object-oriented language which supports interfaces (or is able to simulate them, for example with multiple inheritance of abstract classes), it is up to the classes `Leaf` and `Composite` how they implement the `Component` interface. They can do so by inheriting from a class which already implements `Component`, or they can implement it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, Please refer to [This](http://codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/object-composition-using-chain-of-responsibility) from coding helmet, its a really good sample that implements some design patterns and composition is the glue that lets leaf classes encapsulate and isolate behavior from other classes.

I hope this sample help to get my idea.
 Regards!